# How to display the background color with text smoothly after hovering on the icon?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am using font awesome icon. When the user hovers over the icon then text with the background will display on the screen linearly.

My issues are

1) How to remove the space between each icon. (Space is showing because I am using span with text).

2) When hovering to the icon then the background color is displaying from 0 to 100%. I need directly display 100% when hover.

3) When I a hovering to twitter then I need only facebook icon should linearly slide not a LinkedIn icon.

I know it looks like homework but I tried some code but it's not working for me.

I found the example https://codepen.io/renaudtertrais/full/GfaCE/

When hovering on the icon it is going to the right side I need left side.

Hope someone can help me out in this.

```css
.header_social {
    text-align: center;
}
.header_social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.header_social ul li {
    margin: 02px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
.header_social ul li a { 
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none; 
    position: relative;
}
.header_social i {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -6px;
}

.header_social ul li a span {
 background: #ff0000;
 border-radius: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.header_social ul li:hover span{
    padding: 6px 35px 6px 22px;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
}

.fa-facebook { background-color: #3B5998; }
.fa-twitter { background-color: #1DA1F2; }
.fa-linkedin { background-color: #0077B5; }
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header_social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>Facebook</span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>Twitter</span><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>LinkedIn</span><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: for your 2 point remove the `-webkit-transition-duration` property from the style.

Comment: @AjaySinghDeopa, I removed but it's jumping when to hover over the icon

Comment: Apply the `-webkit-transition-property: all;` and `-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;` to your `.header_social ul li a span` instead of `.header_social ul li:hover span`

Comment: @Xoog, Same output coming as in my question.

Comment: Ah sorry, @Hybreeder I misunderstood, let me take another look.

Comment: So the effect you are after is the icons should stay in the same place, unless it is hovered and then anything to the left should move further left?  It is unclear what your end goal is.  Please can you calrify

Comment: @Pete, If user hover over the Twitter icon then background color and text should force the facebook icon to slide left side. if hover over on LinkedIn then background color with text should force the facebook and twitter icon to slider left side. so that my text should display properly.

Comment: @Pete, if you check my snippet output, When I hover over  Twitter icon facebook icon slide let side but the LinkedIn icon is also going to right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to animate your `span` width. No need to use `position:absolute` here

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.header_social {
  text-align: center;
}

.header_social ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header_social ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header_social ul li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.header_social i {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index:9;
  position:relative;
}

.header_social ul li a span {
  background: #ff0000;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity:0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.header_social ul li a:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  opacity:1;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background-color: #0077B5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header_social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><span>Facebook</span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>Twitter</span><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>LinkedIn</span><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly.Appreciate your support. Thanks, @Bhuwan, Upvote from my side.